# Length of edges not logical compared to dimension of object

Tags: edges, dimensions, measurement

I am trying to create a object with some precise dimensions.
Therefore, I need to also know precise lengths from the edges.

I found out how ot display them, but the values there just don't make any sense:

Dimension of the object:
[image]

Length of the edges from one face:
[image]

How can I display the "real" length of the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Object* mode, select your object and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*.

You've also tweaked the *Delta Transform* values:

[image]

A solution I've just found is to create a simple cube, merge your object with this cube (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) then separate it with <kbd>P</kbd>, it won't have any delta transform values anymore.

Comment: When I apply> scale, the object gets totally "dis"-sized and nothing looks like before. But at least, yes, when doing, and then both dimensions seams to match. How can I achive this, without breaking everything?

Comment: what di you mean by disized? maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: WHen doing, it's getting veeeery small. and all sizes are changing ratio to each other.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/8060fe3742d542f7876ff3785dbed4dc

Comment: Your object has delta transform values, i've edited my answer

Comment: WHen editing the delta transformation, it's again changing the object totally. and the Merge and separate leaves the object as it was after separating.

Comment: don't tweak the delta transform values, merge your object to another one (select your object, shift select the new one, press Ctrl J), then separate it, the delta transform values are removed

Comment: Ah, did did not work in first place, as I first selected the cube and then my object before merge. Now, by changing order it worked!

Comment: But how can I resize the object, like I do with scaling, without changing the scale, but only the dimensions - so that the length in edit mode stay 1:1 proportinal to the dimensions

Comment: do it in Edit mode?

Comment: But in edit mode I cannot set precise values. I just create a cylinder. and want it's dimensions to be 53 x 53 * 10 mm. When setting, the whole scale and length in edit mode are useless. How can I create an object, ob this exact size?

Comment: I'm a bit lost as your problem is several days old, what if you do it in Object mode (see the dimensions in the N panel) then apply the scale with Ctrl A to keep it 1:1:1? Also, there are some addons for good mesh and object measurement but I 'm not familiar with measurement in Blender enough

Comment: If you think it worth a new question, don't hesitate to do it, and explain with a simple example